# A trouble with a wireless mouse

Tags: mouse, bluetooth

I've connected a USB/Bluetooth wireless mouse.

When I don't touch it during an extended period of time and then move, the cursor does not move (and I do not see the red light in the mouse). It starts working again after I press the button.

Why? What happens?

I use recent Debian Linux.

Comment: Sounds like a driver issue.  The device is going in a low powered state.  It requires a button press to get out of it.

Comment: I think it's more by design, if you walk away from your pc and aren't using your mouse keeping it 'alive' in a ready state uses more battery. It wouldn't know how long to wait before it powered down. Have a look at the documentation, there might be a way to alter this idle time but my guess is it's built into the HW

Comment: Power saving mode...  If you don't want lag or to worry about waking up wireless mice (which sleep to *attempt to be helpful*), I would suggest a wired mouse.

Comment: Sigma, model SI9126 or Sl9126

Comment: @Moses - We are talking about an Linux operating system. The driver support likely is very generic.

Comment: @Ramhound My mistake, I read too quickly.